# Running arithmatics through big data in python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, module

I am getting data that has over 2 million columns and that data runs fast through pandas and I want to apply linear regression to this equation and it takes a very long time to process through normal python code. The equation computes every single column value of `price Closes` and that takes a very long time. Would numpy or any other library be more efficient in processing this data and is there a function that could increase this process by a good amount?

```
%%time
%matplotlib notebook
import pandas as pd
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from copy import deepcopy
from itertools import groupby
minute_2015_20 = 'input.csv'
data =pd.read_csv(minute_2015_20, low_memory=False)
#reverses all the table data values
data1 = data.iloc[::-1].reset_index(drop=True)
data1
```

[image]

Comment: **[No Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/)** of code or data. Always provide a [mre] with code, **data, errors, current output, and expected output**, as **[formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, plot images are okay. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The code shown, does not perform any calculations, so no one can properly answer the question. That said, `numpy` is a `pandas` dependency, so `pandas` has many of the same vectorized operations.

Answer (score 0):

- Since I don't actually know your approach, first thought would be to make sure you are running a vectorized operation rather than a loop.
- If you are already doing that, you can try parallelism on the chunks of data.
  This should make the operations faster.
- Another approach ,provided you have access to a GPU, would be to convert it to tensor and perform the actions on a GPU.